# I have Nvidia Geforce on Ubuntu 14.04 , But don't know how to use it or install it on Ubuntu. Please help?

Tags: 14.04, nvidia

I have an Nvidia GPU and Intel CPU but I don't know how to enable or install them on Ubuntu 14.04. I don't know anything , I want to play Dota 2 .. so wanted to get my Nvida geforce to work.. I don't even know the model of my laptop.

The output to `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` is:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 21bc
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev ff)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 21bc
```

Comment: Open a terminal and execute :  lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D' ... please edit your question with the output. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intel open source graphics drivers are already installed.

To install the NVIDIA drivers - open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352  
sudo reboot
```

Execute this command : `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'`

You will additionally see : `Kernel driver in use: nvidia`

The complete output will show you something like this :

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'  
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)  
Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 3501  
Kernel driver in use: i915  

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M] (rev a2)  
Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 3501  
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Comment: Still showing Kernel Driver : i915  :(  What does it mean ?

Comment: Yeah i can see.. But no..  I shall show you the output. I guess it has something to do with the drivers or something. Output is this.

Comment: aradhya@aradhya-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 21bc
 Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev ff)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 21bc
aradhya@aradhya-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$

Comment: Using X.org X server - Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau(Open source) ...

There are other two options too..

Comment: @AshiSood : This means that the drivers are not installed - please boot into BIOS and check whether there is a switch to enable the NVIDIA adapter or switchable graphics mode ... afterwards repeat the installation as described in the answer ! :)

Comment: How to do that ?

Comment: @AshiSood : Please check this in the manual of your notebook - you have to press the F2 or another F key to enter the BIOS ... every hardware is different - or in case you cannot find it, ask the HP support team. :)

Comment: There isn't anything like that. In the addition driver there was another option of propetriory driver of Nvidia.. the recommmended one. i chose that.. but still kernel driver not showing Nvidia.. :(

Comment: @AshiSood : Did you reboot the system after you marked the recommended NVIDIA drivers and the installation finished ? If not, the open source drivers are still in use until the next time you reboot ! :)

Comment: Hey ! It's Showing Kernel Driver in use now...
Does it mean my Nvidia card is working ?  If  Yes.. Then next time if i want to turn it off and turn it on again what to do?

Comment: @AshiSood : Yes, you have the NVIDIA drivers installed successfully and are using the proprietary NVIDIA drivers now ... when you want to switch back to the open source drivers, you have to uninstall the NVIDIA drivers. :)

Comment: Hey i switched back using that nvidia setting prime method.. and now i am  not getting much options in the nvidia setting .. it is not even showing the nvidia graphic now? WHat happened?

Comment: @AshiSood : The options are only for the NVIDIA graphics - switch back to NVIDIA and they are present ! :)